# Windows Template Studio WPF Navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationservice, windows-template-studio

I have a simple WPF app (code-behind) and would like to navigate from one view to another in code-behind.

In UWP, I could do this

```cs
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(destinationView), "myParam");
```

since the NavigationService was a public static class.

Could someone explain how this can be done with the WPF project?

Template Studio Settings

```xml
<genTemplate:Item Name="generator" Value="Template Studio"/>
<genTemplate:Item Name="wizardVersion" Version="v5.1" />
<genTemplate:Item Name="projectType" Value="SplitView" />
<genTemplate:Item Name="framework" Value="CodeBehind" />
<genTemplate:Item Name="platform" Value="Wpf" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone explain how this can be done with the WPF project?

Just inject your view(s) with an `INavigationService`:

```
public partial class SomePage : Page
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService
    public MainPage(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
    ...
}
```

Look at the generated `MainPage.xaml.cs` class for yet an example.

Comment: One related question - why didn't I need to make changes to the code that creates the view; I assumed I would've needed to add an argument since the constructor has the (INavigationService navigationService) parameter.